# Can I use ASP.Net WebApi for Unity Server?

Tags: rest, csv, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api, server

I have created a project in unity in which data is taken from the user, and then saved in a csv format in the device. Now, I am looking for a way in which this data will be uploaded in the server. For server purpose, I am using the WebAPI of ASP.Net. I have created a proper WebAPI and checked it with Swagger too. Now, when I run the code, I think as I am not sure, the data is passed from Unity as the WebAPI project opens up, but when the WebAPI projects get opened, it shows null value as no file is updated there.

I have tried to different ways and files to post from Unity.
String file

```
private IEnumerator UploadStringCoroutine() 
{
 string stringValue = "Hello World"; // The string value to send
 using (UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(serverUrl, "POST"))
 {
   byte[] stringBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringValue);
   www.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(stringBytes);
   www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer(); // Set the content type header to indicate plain text
   www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
   yield return www.SendWebRequest();
   if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success) 
    { 
      Debug.Log("String data uploaded successfully!");
      Debug.Log("Server response: " + www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
   else
    {
      Debug.LogError("Failed to upload string data. Error: " + www.error);
    }
 }
}
```

CSV file content

```
    private IEnumerator UploadCSVCoroutine(string filePath)
    {
        // Read the content of the CSV file as binary data
        byte[] csvBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        // Create a UnityWebRequest to POST the binary data to the server
        UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(serverUrl, "POST");
        UploadHandlerRaw uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(csvBytes);
        www.uploadHandler = uploadHandler;
        www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

        // Set the content type to indicate binary data
        www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        // Send the request
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        // Check the result of the request
        if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log("CSV file uploaded successfully!");
            Debug.Log("Server response: " + www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to upload CSV file. Error: " + www.error);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to convert csv to json also but the I got the same type of error. And this is the code in WebApi Solution written in Controller.cs

```
        [HttpPost("read-employee-csv")]
        public IActionResult GetEmployeeCSV([FromBody] string csvContent)
        {
            byte[] csvBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent); // Convert the content to bytes
            var stream = new MemoryStream(csvBytes); // Create a MemoryStream

            var employees = _csvService.ReadCSV<Coordinate>(stream); // Pass the MemoryStream

            return Ok(employees);
        }
```

And CSVService.cs file consist the code below which is called by _csvService in above code

```
        public IEnumerable<T> ReadCSV<T>(Stream file)
        {
            try
            {
                var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                using var reader = new StreamReader(file);
                using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config);

                // Read and parse the CSV data into a strongly-typed IEnumerable<T>
                return csv.GetRecords<T>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions or validation errors here
                throw ex;
            }
```

Honestly speaking, I have no idea regarding server upload, either in unity or webapi, and I have been coding based on whatever information I got after my searches. I know there are mistakes in the code but I don't know what are they and I am stuck in this for very long so little help and guide will be great. If there is an alternative way for WebAPI, please tell me. Any kind of help is great. And please forgive me if I have asked any dumb question as I have already wrecked my brain with this. :-(

Comment: i dont see you use form variables, i see you set form data, but if you just use form variables, and send them like a webpage would, maybe that works?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get what exactly are you telling me to do. Can you tell me which line are you talking about. I am coding this part with no knowledge so please explain me a little bit. Are you talking about the csvContent?

Comment: Im not prepared to write a tutorial.  Google.

Comment: I have googled it, couldn't find any answer that why asking here.

Comment: Sorry. But i dont believe you when unitys manual even has examples

Comment: Yes, I know there are example. I have tried those ways too. But I was not able to pass the proper data and I did not even know what was the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving a simple solution on how I have send the data from Unity to backend mysql db using Web Api.

**Unity Code**

```cs
private IEnumerator UploadStringCoroutine() 
{
    string stringValue = "Hello World"; // The string value to send
    string serverURL = "Your API URL";
    WWWForm form = new();
    form.AddField("value", stringValue);

    UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(uri, form);
    webRequest.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
    if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.Log("File uploaded successfully!");
        Debug.Log("Server response: " + www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to upload File. Error: " + www.error);
    }
}
```

**API Code**

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("Your API URL")]
public IActionResult methodName([FromForm] string value)
{
    return Ok("Value Fetched " + value);
}
```

As for the CSV file data, I have converted the data into json string file using *Newtonsoft.Json package*
`string jsonFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(csv_file_data);`
and converted back the string in the same way.

This helped me out in data sharing. Hope it helps you too.